# Compiling Raw Objective C with an already compiled executable

Tags: objective-c, executable

I am building an OS X Framework and I have also built a command line and its in the frameworks resources folder because the framework needs to use it but, I am trying to figure out if I can compile an already compiled executable (the command line) into the frameworks executable so they combine?

Comment: I think you mean _linking_. This means combining of compiled files.

Comment: Maybe, can you please explain if I can link an already compiled executable to an executable that I am compiling

Comment: You should not link your program to the lib, because it contains a main function. This can lead to errors if want link your lib to another app. Why don't you just execute the progamm?

Comment: Yea I was originally thinking of just adding the command line (already compiled executable) to the frameworks resources folder (I know how to do) but I was just wondering maybe there was a way I could embed the command line into the frameworks executable so I could 'protect' the command line so other developers can't get it and use it for them selves, I want them to use the entire framework

Comment: Do you have the sources of the command line tool?

Comment: Yea I still have the sources but I am not trying to connect the command line tool source to the rest of the code because for some reason if I implement the same command line code into the framework, It doesn't execute the same??? but It works separately as a command line so I basically want to "bundle" the command line separately but inside the framework executable

Comment: You can separate the logic from the "execution" (main function) code. Put the logic into your framework, and link it when building the command line. Now you can use the logic from the command line and from other apps, too.